# Кидает в документ vector

Tags: c++, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, k, n;
    double s = 0, j;
    cin >> n;
    vector <int> v(n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> v[i];
        s += v[i];
    }
    s /= 2;
    j = s;
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    i = 0;
    while (s >= 0)
    {
        s -= v[i];
        ++i;
    }
    k = i;
    int z = 0;
    i = n - 1;
    while (j >= 0)
    {
        s -= v[i];
        ++z;
        --i;
    }
    if (n == 1)
        cout << 1;
    else {
        if (k < z)
            cout << (k + 1);
        else
            cout << (z + 1);
    }
    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Забавная у вас программа...
Допустим, после ввода и

```
s /= 2;
j = s;
```

получим `j>0`. И сколько после этого будет работать вот этот цикл:

```
while (j >= 0)
{
    s -= v[i];
    ++z;
    --i;
}
```

Ровно до момента `i < 0` - т.е. выхода за границу массива... что вы и продемонстрировали на рисунке.

Comment: Да огромное спасибо, вроде все перепроверял, но видимо не до конца